# Jquery adding multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem, here it goes, i have a text in a div which is generated dynamically, so i want to wrap it inside a div for further styling, and when i wrap it inside a div, i want to append a div before it for an image. when i run the code i wrote, i see multiple divs getting generated

```
var pageInitialized = false;
$(function() {
if (pageInitialized) return;
pageInitialized = true;

$('.entry-content').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).contents().wrap("<div class='alert_content'></div>");
});

$('.alert_content').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).before("<div class='error_image'></div>");
});

[![The output is as follows int he image][1]][1]});
```

Comment: Can you show us the html code??

Comment: Also, can you show use the expected html output you desire?

Comment: its in jsp, dynamically generated. the output should be a single red circle in the left and the text at the right. there is just apiece of text in the div and i want to do all these stuff

Comment: Not the visual description, I mean the html code, which will be dynamically generated, Make a guess and kindly tell me how it is going to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `$(v).contents().wrap("<div class='alert_content'></div>");` which wrap each child of `entry-content` with an `alert_content`. Instead if you want a single `alert_content` for a `entry-content` then use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) like

```js
$('.entry-content').each(function(i, v) {
  $(v).wrapInner("<div class='alert_content'></div>");
}).prepend("<div class='error_image'></div>");

//$('.alert_content').before("<div class='error_image'></div>");
```

```css
.entry-content {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.alert_content {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.error_image {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry-content">
  <div>div</div>
  <input />text
</div>

<div class="entry-content">
  <div>div</div>
  <input />text
</div>

<div class="entry-content">
  <div>div</div>
  <input />text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
$('.entry-content').each(function(i, v) {
  $($(this).html()).wrap("<div class='alert_content'></div>");
});

$('.alert_content').each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).before("<div class='error_image'></div>");
});
```

Comment: html().wrap) is not a function bro